# IUserClaimsPrincipalFactory`1 not registered error in IndentityServer implementation

Tags: identityserver4, asp.net-core-identity

I am getting below exception even after registering the AddDefaultIdentity

```
System.InvalidOperationException: Service type: IUserClaimsPrincipalFactory`1 not registered.
```

Here's the Identity registration code:

```
services.AddDefaultIdentity<ApplicationUser>(options =>
            {
                //Disable account confirmation.
                options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = false;
                options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedEmail = false;
                options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedPhoneNumber = false;
            })
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();
```

And here's the IdentityServer code:

```
        var builder = services.AddIdentityServer()
            .AddInMemoryApiScopes(IdentityServerConfig.ApiScopes)
            .AddInMemoryIdentityResources(IdentityServerConfig.IdentityResources)
            .AddInMemoryApiResources(IdentityServerConfig.ApiResources)
            .AddInMemoryClients(IdentityServerConfig.Clients)
            .AddAspNetIdentity<IdentityUser>();
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I spent hours solving this typo.

The problem was that my registration was wrong.

I was working with `ApplicationUser` but I was registering `IdentityUser` in the identity server.

I fixed my problem by setting the `ApplicationUser` in both `AddIdentityServer()` and `AddDefaultIdentity()`.

Here's the working code: .Net Core Identity

```
services.AddDefaultIdentity<ApplicationUser>(options =>
            {
                //Disable account confirmation.
                options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = false;
                options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedEmail = false;
                options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedPhoneNumber = false;
            })
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();
```

IdentityServer4:

```
var builder = services.AddIdentityServer()
                .AddInMemoryApiScopes(IdentityServerConfig.ApiScopes)
                .AddInMemoryIdentityResources(IdentityServerConfig.IdentityResources)
                .AddInMemoryApiResources(IdentityServerConfig.ApiResources)
                .AddInMemoryClients(IdentityServerConfig.Clients)
                .AddAspNetIdentity<ApplicationUser>();
```

Notice the use of `ApplicationUser`.
I posted question here so that I remember it next time.

Comment: Indeed. Beware of using ApplicationUser (derived class from IdentityUser) in some places and the base IdentityUser class in others. I spent hours trying to find the solution.

Comment: In my case the ApplicationUser was wrong and IdentityUser in both cases fixed the issue

Answer (score 9):

I fixed this error by changing the order. I had

```
var builder = services.AddIdentityServer()
    .AddInMemoryIdentityResources(Config.IdentityResources)
    .AddInMemoryClients(Config.Clients)
    .AddAspNetIdentity<ApplicationUser>();

builder.AddDeveloperSigningCredential();

services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
    options.UseMySql(Configuration.GetConnectionString("ApplicationDbContext")));

services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>()
    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
    .AddDefaultTokenProviders();
```

Now I have:

```
services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
    options.UseMySql(Configuration.GetConnectionString("ApplicationDbContext")));

services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>()
    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
    .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

var builder = services.AddIdentityServer()
    .AddInMemoryIdentityResources(Config.IdentityResources)
    .AddInMemoryClients(Config.Clients)
    .AddAspNetIdentity<ApplicationUser>();

builder.AddDeveloperSigningCredential();
```